# Is there dh_make analog for rpm packages

Tags: rpm, deb, rpm-spec, debhelper

Existing source distributions can be debianized easily using dh_make, but I failed to find similar tool for rpm packages. Are there any, or the only way is to write spec file manually

Comment: If it exists, I have no such knowledge. I always write a spec file...

Answer (score 0):

Debian has the information in several files in `debian/` directory. On the other hand RPM package is made only by *.spec file.

If you run:

```
vim foo.spec
```

where foo.spec does not exist, vim should load generic template for spec file.

When you install `rpmdevtools` package, then there is command:

```
rpmdev-newspec -m --type ruby
```

for list of available types see /etc/rpmdevtools where the templates reside.

And of course then there are lots of generator, which can create SRPM or spec file just from the name of the module:

```
pyp2rpm <some PyPI module>
gem2rpm <some rubygem module>
cpanspec <some CPAN module>
```

And probably some others.

Comment: that's not exactly what i was looking for, but it helped. Thanks :)